# Visual Studio unable to load necessary dll's to run project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, windows-xp

I am trying to run a project in Visual Studio 2010, and for some reason it seems like I can't... the command-line window is closed instantly and the debug info is the following:

```
'exercise01.exe': Loaded 'E:\e\work spaces\C++ projects\exercise01\Debug\exercise01.exe', Symbols loaded.
'exercise01.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'exercise01.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'exercise01.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[5900] exercise01.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

what might be the cause for these two dll's to not get loaded? and is the fact program exited with code 0 related to my program not running, or is there another problem?

I know others have published such questions before, but unfortunately I couldn't fine any useful info anywhere, so forgive me if I'm re-uploading a question... I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to programming in C, and in Visual Studio in general, so please have patience  (:

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check: Are these files actually there. Maybe windows is installed in a different directory and an environment variable is pointing to the wrong place.

If the files are there it is probably an authentication problem. You are running from the command line window. You may be running this in the context of NETWORK SERVICE. Try starting the command window, by right clicking on the menu and selecting "run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your program was started and quickly ran to completion.

When you start debugging a console mode VS project, if your program doesn't stop somewhere or hit a breakpoint, it'll just run the program and when the program exits the window will close.

This is different behavior than if you run the program without the debugger - VS will keep the console window open when the program terminates.

Anyway, you can wither set a breakpoint on `main()` (or some other convenient location) or instead of simply starting the program with the debugger, you can "single step" into it, which will immediately break into the debugger and stop executuion.